# setup_postdata() does not seem to be working?

Tags: get-posts

I am not sure why but I have used `get_posts()` to query for some data. Then I used `setup_postdata()` ... I think its used so that I can use functions like `the_permalink()` etc with the new post data?

```
<?php foreach ($childPosts as $cp) : setup_postdata($cp); ?>

<article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
  <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(($hasOutputNotFeaturedDiv) ? 'thumb-small' : null) ?></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  <p class="more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more ...</a></p>
  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
</article>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but it appears that only `the_excerpt` contains the new post data value, why is that? I find that if I use `echo get_the_permalink($cp)` it works ok. But I think the shorter version will be better

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I could be wrong, but from what I'm seeing, "setup_postdata()" should be used when doing a custom select query (not just query_posts):
http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

As well, if you want to use tags like "the_title()" and "the_permalink()" with that custom select query ... you'll need to use the variable name **$post** specifically (not another variable name) in setup_postdata() - AS WELL - you should call **global $post** before your "foreach" loop...

So basically follow that example in that codex link. And don't change the variable name $post - otherwise it breaks it.

HTH

Comment: "you should call global $post" . YES! Why is that not in the Codex

Comment: 2021 and this still causes me issues lol

Answer (score 40):

Replace the

```
foreach ( $childPosts as $cp ) : setup_postdata( $cp );
```

with

```
foreach ( $childPosts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
```

So you need to use the exact `$post` variable along with the `setup_postdata()`.

Comment: This fixed the the problem I was having. Cheers mate

Comment: Somebody buy this man a beer! Thank you.. Any idea why/how a local variable can mess with `setup_postdata()` ?

Comment: Weird. It seems so illogical to require a specific variable name when you're passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @Gavin I don't know why more people don't question how weird some of the WP logic is. The strangeness is just normal now it seems ...

Comment: Another beautiful implementation by Automattticcc.

Answer (score 11):

`global post;` does not work with `setup_postdata($post);` if you want to use the `the_title()` family of commands etc.

It's in https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

Instead use

```
// global $post; setup_postdata($post_object); //don't do this!
setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
```

...also make sure your `$post_object` is a valid WP_Post object.

Comment: This answer actually solves the problem, instead of scolding the OP :p

Answer (score 10):

Depending on where you are using setup_postdata() (if it is not in the main loop, or in a function/sidebar widget, for example), you may also need to declare -

```
global $post;
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 4):

2 important things to make this work,

1. use global $post variable to setup the postdata, else the loop functions will not see your custom post object.
2. VERY IMPORTANT: make sure to call `wp_reset_postdata()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) at the end of the loop else you may have weird errors which will be very difficult to debug.

   ```
    <?php
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'offset'         => 1,
        'category'       => 1
    ) );

    if ( $myposts ) :
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) :
          setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When querying posts just use the normal loop with a set of arguments passed into it. Then reset the query at the end.

```
<?php 

    // makes query respect paging rules
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');

    // defining the arguements for the custom loop
    $variablenameQuery = array(
        'post_type'                 => 'seating-charts',
        'post_status'               => 'publish',
        'cust_tax_name'             => 'custom-tax-term',
        'posts_per_page'            => -1, // neg 1 means all posts
        'orderby'                   => 'date',
        'order'                     => 'ASC',
        'paged'                     => $paged,
    ); // end query

    // pass result into query_posts to get result
    query_posts($variablenameQuery);

?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php // Individual Post Styling ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // paged navigation - next post, previous post... ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <h3>Ooops looks like there was an issue. Please <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/contact" title="Contact Us">get in touch</a> with us and we'll get the problem fixed.</h3>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- resets the WordPress Query -->
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But just for understanding, do you know why `setup_postdata()` does not seem to work? Did I use it wrongly?

Comment: @jiewmeng - See if using `$post` instead of `$cp` fixes the problem.

Comment: I vote for the fix @t31os suggests. The examples on the codex show the usage like that and $post is a special variable in WordPress so it might do more inside a loop than what you've used.

Comment: @t31os, @curtismchale, that didn't appear to work too. It still gives the same result

Comment: Old, I know but DO NOT use query_posts() unless you KNOW you need it. It's inefficient. See this helpful image for the alternatives: https://www.rarst.net/images/query_functions.png