# the title not working from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to show a list of the latest 3 custom post types in the footer, and while I am getting the permalink ok for the href, the title is not displaying. 
Here is the code I put in the footer:

```
$postslist = get_posts('numberposts=3&order=DESC&orderby=date&post_type=class');
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

A plugin is generating the post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the WP_Query  Before your Code:

```
<?php 
$allCat = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  =>  'category-products',
            'field'     =>  'slug',
            'terms'     =>  'your-slug',

            )
    ) 
);

?>
    <?php $all_product = new WP_Query($allCat); ?>
    <?php if($all_product -> have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while($all_product -> have_posts()) : 
            $all_product -> the_post(); ?>     

             <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try globalizing $post before your foreach as mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9834/setup-postdata-does-not-seem-to-be-working)

```
$postslist = get_posts('numberposts=3&order=DESC&orderby=date&post_type=class');
global $post;
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```